# Data getting lost from Behavior's beforeValidate() to Model's beforeSave()

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.2

**UPDATE:**

It appears the slug doesn't save when using `saveAll()`.  I have it doing a `save()` immediately after the `saveAll`, and it works now, but it's an obvious kludge, and I'd rather get it working with `saveAll` if possible... I have other models that should be generating slugs, and I'd rather not have to dual save every time just to create a slug.

---

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

Trying to implement this behavior:  https://github.com/vduglued/CakePHP-Sluggable-Behavior/blob/master/sluggable.php

It was working fine, but recently it stopped... I'm not sure what the issue is, or what we changed, but **I've narrowed down the problem**.

In the behavior's `beforeValidate();` function, it adds the correct slug to the data.  When I debug `$model->data` at that point, it shows:

```
Array('Article' => array('slug'=>'test_1234')  ...
```

among other data.

If I remove THAT debug and debug `$this->data` in the `beforeSave()` of my Article model, it shows all the data, but NOT the slug field that should have been added via the `SluggableBehavior`.

I don't think I should have to alter the behavior, as I thought it was working fine before..but maybe a recent update in CakePHP versions changed something with how Behaviors and Models communicate?

Comment: Dave can you post the controller action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in saveAssociated(), update your cake core

Comment: To be more specific for future users, according to the CakePHP.org site, they recently added a fix: "Model::saveMany(), saveAssociated() correctly save data that was modified in a beforeValidate() callback."